# How to protected/private class #1 but allow wrapper class #2 to be public and containing in-house class #1?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to have wrapper class be exposed as public but other class be private/protected inside the wr

Let's say this script is in DLL file.

```
protected class Class1
{
    public string Foo1() { return "Hello World!"; }
}

public class Class2
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();

    public Class1 Class1_Test 
    {
       get { return class1; }
    }
}
```

Let's say I have Windows Form or webpage.

Here I called `Class2.Class1_Test.Foo1()`, I am getting a `"Hello World!"` value.

How do I make both `Class1()` and `CLass1.Foo1()` not be visible to the Windows Form?

I am getting syntax error complaining that Class2 is inaccessible due to protection level.

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about `Class2`, from your example, the `Class1 class1 = new Class1();` is the problem.

Comment: Just out of interest; why are you doing this ? I've always been interested in the reasons for wanting to do this sort of thing!

Comment: Matthew - Yes, Visual Studio show the red underlines..

Comment: `protected class` yields a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, if you have a separate assembly containing `Class1` and `Class2`, you could give `Class1` an internal constructor, so you could only instantiate it in your assembly.

```
public class Class1
{
    internal Class1() 
    {
    }

    public string Foo1() { return "Hello World!"; }
}

public class Class2
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();

    public Class1 Class1_Test 
    {
       get { return class1; }
    }
}
```

Anything outside of the assembly that tries to instantiate `Class1` will receive the error

```
The type 'MyAssembly.Class1' has no constructors defined
```

Comment: After of a few days of experiment when I learned that interface doesn't support constructor.  I also learned inner classes or abstracts does not hide the class for external assemblies.  So, I decided to accept your answer as it is in the end, it is the only way to accomplish this but yet class remain visible to external assemblies.  :-/

Answer (score 3):

By exposing protected class through public interface.

```
public interface IClass1
{
    string Foo1();
}

protected class Class1 : IClass1 { ... }

public class Class2
{
    ...
    public IClass1 Class1_Test { ... }
}
```

Comment: How would `Class2` ever get an instance of something that implemented `IClass1`?

Comment: +1 An interface is the best way to hide the implementation but still expose it to consumers. The interface declaration should not contain the `public` keyword in the method (everything in an interface is public by definition). The Class1 can be protected if it's declared **within** another class, but if it's on it's own, it can only be `public` or `internal`

Comment: @Matthew Dots in my code represent copied code. Class2 would get an instance of Class1 in the same way as in fletchsod's code.

Comment: @abatishchev If protected class was possible in fletchsod's code, it must have been a nested type - which can be protected.

Comment: @lisp - Is there a good documenation in layman term for eaiser reading and visualize it in our mind?

Comment: @fletchsod I might understand your dissatisfaction with this answer, if the reason for wanting to hide Class1 was to stop it from apearing in InteliSense or something like that. I suggested interface, because it does what you wanted and is generally a good practice (see e.g. [Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)).

Comment: @fletchsod If, for some reason, you would like to hide interface too, your solution is to completely wrap Class1 and instead of `public Class1 Class1_Test` implement `public string Foo1()` in `Class2` with a body: `{ return class1.Foo1(); }`, but you have to do this for every property of Class1 you want to be available to 'the outside world'.

Comment: @lisp - I'm not really dissatified.  I had looked at some examples from Google search on interface and found it to be mind boggling because the author over complicate it.  I'm willing to give interface a try.  My plan is to use your example plus many different sample demo to practice writing interface to find the strength and weakness in hte sample demo and make it better, to make it fit better into the visual studio solutions w/ over 30 projects.  ;-)

Comment: So, is there good documentation in layman term for several different examples of using Interface?  Thanks.

Comment: @fletchsod This tutorial might be what you're looking for: [c# interface based development](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_interrfaces03052006095933AM/csharp_interrfaces.aspx). Or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners)

Comment: Oh darn!  The interface does not support constructor with passing in of parameter.  I'll clicked your answser as accepted answer.  Now I'm thinking could abstract get the job done?  Or do a nest class.

Comment: @fletchsod You cannot declare a constructor in interface, because you cannot instantiate an interface. But you can still define a constructor in Class1 and Class2 can call this constructor. Where there are dots in my code, it will be identical to yours.